# can nonresident alien (NRA) stock loss carryover/be calculated as cost basis?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, non-resident, capital-loss

I am a nonresident alien NRA in California. I am an ordinary employee in a tech company, that's my job. I have no business. Aside from my job I trade stock by myself. So if I have capital gain, my tax rate is flat, which is 30%.

Suppose I lost 100K in tax year 2020. And in tax year 2021 I gained 10K. Now, the question is, in tax year 2021, do I need to pay capital gain tax for the 10K gain, or I don't need to, because if my previous 100K loss is carried over (deducted), in tax year 2021 I am still having 90K loss?

So you can see this question is not about deducting loss against taxable income. It's about loss carryover. If I need to pay 10K gain tax, I am fucked up as NRA.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no capital loss carryover (or deduction) for US-nonresident non-effectively-connected income. But if you aren't a student/scholar (F,J,M,Q) or diplomat (A,G), the only way I see for you to 'fail' the substantial presence test and be NRA is if you were here less than half the year, and in that case your cap gains aren't subject to US tax.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 very similar question -- i was a resident and accumulated a short-term capital loss carryover of $10,000. the next year i became a non-resident but i have some US dividend income on which i owe taxes. is the capital loss carryover available to offset anything? or did it get vaporized when i became a non-resident alien?